# Has a program ever successfully run on Wine, but failed on native Windows?

Tags: windows, wine, compatibility

This is admittedly a more theoretical question looking for objective grounds; forgive me if I chose the wrong stack for it.

Wine is a compatibility layer for Microsoft Windows, allowing programs native to it to run on Linux, BSD, and other POSIX operating systems. However, Windows is a moving target, and Wine is produced through blackbox reverse engineering—so it isn't always spot-on until after at least a few updates.

In theory, I think Wine could support some programs that would fail on native Windows, by the same reasoning; but I'm not aware of any specific examples. Hopefully someone on Stack Exchange will be able to highlight something anecdotal.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. There are quite a few programs that ran fine on older versions of Windows, and still run on current Wine, but don't run on the latest Windows. Happened a lot when Windows started having permissions and programs that poked directly into the Windows directory started failing, but Wine wasn't affected in the same way. I'm sure it's possible to craft a program that works under Wine, but doesn't work under any official Windows; but why would anyone have ever wanted to release such a program?

Comment: An interesting point. Actually I'm looking into how feasible testing a program through Wine is, without rebooting to Windows before every release. (Linux is, exclusively, the development environment for several target platforms.) Of course we'll be running it native now and then, but the only real dependency is SDL2 and I've seen no real difference as of yet. So it's less targeting Wine, and more ensuring that Wine, for Windows, is at least as reliable as, say, the Android Emulator for Android.

Comment: @Michael I recommend you rephrase your question to reflect what you’re really trying to determine. “Can Wine be relied upon to test a Windows program?” isn’t the same question as “Has a program ever successfully run on Wine, but failed on native Windows?”

Comment: @Knitt I feel that asking whether a tool can be relied upon is a bit vague, and possibly opinion-oriented, for Stack Exchange's standards. Also, I know that relying entirely on Wine is an invitation for trouble. While my trust for Wine is what I'm tuning here, my actual question is as stated.